# Load a csv file of date and time into oracle database using java

Tags: java, oracle, csv, exception

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;

public class ImportingDate {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try{
        /* Create Connection objects */
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe","SYSTEM","sandp");
        /* Create the insert statement */
        String insertQuery = "Insert into date_tab(workdate) values(to_date(?,'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))";
        PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("D:\\datedata.csv"), ',');
        String[] nextLine;
        int i = 0;
        while((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null)
        {
            i++;
            if (nextLine.length == 1){
                pstmt.setString(1,nextLine[0]);
                i=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Data Successfully Uploaded");
            pstmt.close();
            conn.commit();
            conn.close();
        }

        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

i am getting an error as follows=

java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01843: not a valid month

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3368)
at a.ba.ImportingDate.main(ImportingDate.java:32)
```

i m using eclipse and oracle 10g
how can i fix the problem and insert into table into timestamp datatype.
i have created a table named date_tab(workdate timestamp)

CSV file contains as follows=
15-02-15 17:54:45

18-02-15 18:19:33

20-06-15 18:38:56

23-09-15 19:00:18

22-02-15 19:21:08

26-07-15 19:40:04

21-05-15 20:03:07

25-01-15 20:25:59

28-02-15 20:48:12

27-04-15 00:05:11

Comment: The format in your `to_date` statement is not the same as the format of the dates in your CSV file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace (`dd/mon/yyyy`)

```
String insertQuery = 
  "Insert into date_tab(workdate) values(to_date(?,'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'))";
```

by (`dd-mm-rr`)

```
String insertQuery = 
  "Insert into date_tab(workdate) values(to_date(?,'dd-mm-rr hh24:mi:ss'))";
```

`mon` represents the three letter abbreviation and `mm` is `01` to `12`. Check [this overview](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) for more.

**p.s.**: as per examples you should use `rr` instead of `yyyy` and `-` instead of `/`

Answer (score 2):

i can't try this on my own right now, but i suppose your format-string 'dd/mon/yyyy hh24:mi:ss' is not matching your Date-Strings '15-02-15 17:54:45'.

try to use 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss' instead.

Comment: `yyyy` won't work due to two-digits year `15` - use `rr` instead

Comment: @VGR you're right .. overlooked the two digit year !

Answer (score 0):

update the following code and it will run successfully
            String insertQuery = "Insert into date_tab(workdate) values(to_date(?,'dd/mm/yy hh24:mi:ss'))";